# UIButton setTitle:forState: use UIConrolState() as parameter

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit

I always set UIButton's title as follows

```
aButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
```

However, recently I've seen this

```
aButton.setTitle(title, for: UIControlState())
```

Is it correct way of setting title?

Comment: Yes, if it's not showing you any error, as it may using default state upon initializing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also legal and identical:

```
aButton.setTitle(title, for: [])
```

The reason is that `.normal` *is* the zero option.

**Extra for experts:** During the run-up to Swift 3, `.normal` was abolished, and `[]` or `UIControlState()` were the *only* ways to specify the zero option. This was because of a rule that said that the zero option of an Objective-C option set was not imported into Swift by name at all. However, this blanket application of the rule (which still exists in general) caused massive confusion and complaints, and `.normal` was brought back by popular demand.

Answer (score 0):

both statements have the same result. `aButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)` is the "regular way" to set the button's title though...

Answer (score 0):

Difference between both is simple:

```
aButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
```

set your text only for **normal** state and you have options to set some different text for other **Control states**  as **selected**,**focused**,**highlighted**

but using

```
aButton.setTitle(title, for: UIControlState())
```

is something different
 *as long as it doesnt throw any error*.

Comment: I don't think you're right regarding last statement.